# Deploying config files to PLC

Tags: plc, twincat

Is it possible include arbitrary files (in this case a *.csv*) from a TwinCAT project direct to the Boot directory of a PLC?

By using [`PATH_BOOTPATH`](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclibsystem/html/TcPlcLibSys_E_OpenPath.htm&id=) in the file open/read FBs it is possible to load files from this directory in a convenient manner regardless of whether using a CE or Windows deployment, However deployment of files to this location seems to be the sticking point.

I know that a copy of the project code is included within the *CurrentConfig<Project>.tpzip* file, but this file is not easily accessible from code, or updateable.

I've found the 'Additional Files' section within the system configuration, but it makes little sense.

- Adding a file from inside the project as a 'Relative' path doesn't seem to do anything
- Adding a file from inside the project as an external path includes the file (via symbolic links?) in the 'CurrentConfig.tszip' file, which has the same issues as the .tpzip
- Adding an external file as an external path again includes the file inside of the .tszip.
  [image: Setup of the system "Additional files"]

I'm willing to accept that this might not be possible, but it just feels odd that the `PATH_BOOTPRJ` and `PATH_BOOTPATH` roots are there and not accessing useful paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Deployment](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/3260050187.html&id=)

To quote Beckhoff:

> Deployment is used to set up commands that are to be executed during the installation and startup of an application.

[image: Beckhoff example deployment]

---

The event types are essentially at what stage of the deployment process the command is performed, where the command can either be copying a file or execution of a script/program.

Haven't performed extensive testing but between absolute/relative pathing and execution this should solve nearly all issues with deployment configuration.